# REST call TCP handshake

Tags: rest, http, networking, web, tcp

So if I visit a website through a browser, I know an HTTP GET call is made using TCP underneath where a 3 way handshake is made before the request is actually sent through to the web server.

If I want to proceed to send REST calls to the webserver, does each call need to repeat the handshake (as REST is stateless, but I don't know if something is done on the TCP transport layer level to maintain a connection)? If not, how is this connection maintained? Is there a way to keep it maintained on the application level?

Answer (score 3):

HTTP versions 1.0 and later support keeping the connection alive at the application level. Punch [HTTP persistent connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) into your favorite search engine.